# Regulated market for points

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, reputation

I propose a market for points. **No reputation is gained or lost in the process.** Please understand what is being proposed before voting/commenting.

The transferred points are not added to the buyer's shown reputation points. They are kept separate and hidden from the public and do not increase reputation. They can only be used to pay a bounty.

The transferred points are not subtracted from the seller's shown reputation points. They are kept separate just to calculate how much the seller has left to sell. If the seller had 5k points and sold 1k he still has 4k to sell and still has 5k reputation.

There is a limit for how much one can sell, say a maximum of 20% of his points. In the above example the seller would not have anything left to sell as he already sold 1k which is 20% of his 5k points.

The points won from bounties paid with transferred points can not be sold and do not count for the calculus of the above limit. Say one had 1,000 points and won 300 points from a bounty paid with transferred points. He now has a total of 1,300 reputation but can only sell 20% of the original 1k points, 200 points.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: YAGNI (that's what he said)

Comment: The voting system is not _I agree -> up_ and _I disagree -> down_. It is to mark usefulness and clearness.

Comment: @Kate I'm talking about money. I have a (very) high paying job and I have been very well paid for most of my long professional life. But to see my contributions turn into money (little) would be an extra joy, kind of a real game. I think many, if not most, of the high skilled participants in StackOverflow would think the same.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Actually on Meta votes are commonly used to show agreement/disagreement, please read the [Meta FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) thoroughly. Also, your question isn't clear at all - you already had to clarify that you're talking about money, still your question doesn't make much sense even with the clarification. Please edit it to explain exactly what it is you are suggesting, and more importantly how it will be beneficial to the community.

Comment: We're stealing all your meta reps with our downvotes.

Comment: No. No, no, no, no, no. No. That's not how the Stack Exchange network of sites operate. Suck it up and earn rep like the rest of us or leave.

Answer (score 7):

Judging by the reception that this proposal has gotten so far, I think you're probably wrong to "think many, if not most, of the high skilled participants in StackOverflow would think the same."

However, you may still be able to "see [your] contributions turn into money (little)." Find a (very) highly paid peer of yours and ask them if they'd like to wager on Stack Overflow. I leave the specifics of the wager to you---an advantage of this solution is that the mechanics of the setup are entirely in your hands. No need for any changes to Stack Overflow!

This won't work if you have no suitable peers, in which case there may simply be no solution. *C'est la vie.*

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps something was lost in translation, but I don't think you grasp what "reputation" means.

> **Reputation**: the estimation in which a person or thing is held, especially by the community or the public generally

Reputation is a rough gauge of how much we trust a given user to behave in the site's best interest. That's what reputation *means*. You absolutely shouldn't be able to buy your way into a better reputation, and if nobody can buy it you have no reason to sell it.

Comment: You didn't read it. Reputation is not transferred. Just hidden points that can only be used to pay bounties.

Answer (score 4):

That just doesn't make any sense.

I could simply buy the points from myself (sockpuppet account) or "trade" the bounty points with another user and start bounties without any impact on my reputation.

Comment: +1 Exactly! You got it! If you don't want to use your reputation or don't have enough reputation to pay a bounty you can buy the points. No change in reputation to any of the seller or the buyer. The only affected will be the one who wins the bounty and will have its reputation raised.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: That's not at all what I meant. With your system in place, I can start bounties without losing reputation and **without paying money**.

Answer (score 3):

Are you seriously asking for money to be paid to answer questions?? ( that's what I'm getting from your post ).

No!  Not only no, but hell no!

That would wreck SO ...

I'm so stupefied by this I can't even come up with anything more cogent/coherent to say...

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea of the reputation system is that you have to *work for the community* to get access to some privileges. [Setting a bounty is one of those privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties). That’s not an accident. It guarantees equal chances for all members. Even a moderator with less than 75 rep could not set a bounty.

Undermining this system with money would a) set a precedent nobody wants and b) discriminate askers with less money.

Comment: _and b) discriminate those with less money_ and reward those with the best answers to win the bounty. This includes those with less money that could also win the bounty. A bounty is only offered when the question is hard and had no good answers and it costs reputation or... money. Both hard to get. As for myself I never offered a bounty. But if I needed some crucial answers to advance some commercial deal I would have no problem in buying the necessary points. And I would be giving reputation to someone competent.

Comment: I was talking about _askers_. Made that more clear in an edit.